# CupertinoTabView doesn't have an "OnPressed()" functionality. How to simulate?

Tags: ios, flutter, setstate, tabview

Okay, I'm having an issue with my program, and I understand kinda WHY it won't work the way I want to, but I don't understand how to fix it.

I'm using the following code to switch tabs in my application.

```
        child: CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
          switch (i) {
            case 0:
              titleChanged = false;
              firstPage = Page1();
              return firstPage;
              break;
            case 1:
              pageTitle = 'Page 2';
              titleChanged = true;
              secondPage = SecondPage();
              return secondPage;
              break;
            default:
              return Container();
          }
        }
```

Now earlier in the code (higher-up in the widget tree) I have the Title of the entire page, which I want to switch back and forth between Page 1 and Page 2.  I can change the text, but I need to do a setState() in order for that change to take effect.

Unfortunately the tabview "buttons" don't ACT like normal buttons, ergo, I can't apply a setState() function to them, otherwise it's calling setState during build.

I've been told perhaps to use an observer, but none of the resources I can find online can really direct me to exactly how to do so.

I'm not certain an observer is the right way to go, but I'm also at the end of my experience, as I'm quite new to flutter.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `onTap` of `CupertinoTabBar` 
Example code update `AppBar` `title` 
code snppet

```
 tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
                  items: [
                    ...
                  ],
                  onTap: (int index) {
                    switch (index) {
                      case 0:
                        _title = "1 first";
                        setState(() {});
                        break;
                      case 1:
                        _title = "2 second";
                        setState(() {});
                        break;
                      case 2:
                        _title = "3 third";
                        setState(() {});
                        break;
                    }
                  },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _title = "1 first";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(_title)),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: CupertinoTabScaffold(
                tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
                  items: [
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        title: Text("First"), icon: Icon(Icons.menu)),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        title: Text("Second"), icon: Icon(Icons.business)),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        title: Text("Third"), icon: Icon(Icons.account_box)),
                  ],
                  onTap: (int index) {
                    switch (index) {
                      case 0:
                        _title = "1 first";
                        setState(() {});
                        break;
                      case 1:
                        _title = "2 second";
                        setState(() {});
                        break;
                      case 2:
                        _title = "3 third";
                        setState(() {});
                        break;
                    }
                  },
                ),
                tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return CupertinoTabView(
                    builder: (context) {
                      switch (index) {
                        case 0:
                          return FirstPage();
                          break;
                        case 1:
                          return SecondPage();
                          break;
                        case 2:
                          return ThirdPage();
                          break;
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text("First"),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: CupertinoButton(
          child: Text("First button"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text("Second"),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: CupertinoButton(
          child: Text("Second button"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text("Thrid"),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: CupertinoButton(
          child: Text("Third button"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tabs have a child property, try using GestureDetector()